# using jquery in nuxt.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, nuxt.js, undefined-behavior

I'm trying out **nuxt.js** for the first time. But I can't get **JQuery** to work.

I've installed the `npm` package alongside with **bootstrap.js** and **popper.js**.

Also added this to the **nuxt.config.js**:

```
vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery'
      })
    ],
```

But when I try to use it in the view it doesn't work.
First I get:

> "$" is not defined

Then when I try to require it by `require $ from 'jquery'`
I get undefined when I try to use `$`.

I'm programming **.Net** usually so this is not my strongest part.

I'm trying to use `$` like so:

```
$.each(this.imageList, function(key, image) {
    formData.append(`images[${key}]`, image)
  })
```

As said it gives me different undefined errors depending if I require it or not.

How can I make it recognize the `$`?

Comment: dont do it. dont use jquery in nuxt. You have vue which covers all of what jquery can do and it will just make project hard to develop and maintain

Comment: What is equalent to my $.each function?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Okey thanks dude! Could you check on my other question about my POST request transforming to a GET :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think jquery can be used everywhere in the project. so global declaration will be best case. you can simply add JQuery in your project ,

1. keep your JQuery.js into static folder
2. just add piece of code into Nuxt.config.js file like below:

> script: [{src: 'jquery-3.3.1.min.js'}]

hope your problem will solve.

see the image:
[image]

you can download JQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: I don't have anything in my static folder :P, but added the 2nd part. Still get $ is undefined.

Comment: just keep your jquery.js file into static folder.

Comment: I don't have a jquery.js file :P

Comment: just download your required JQuery.js file from web, and keep the file into static folder. but keep in mind that same file name should be write in nuxt.config.js file.

Comment: it is a better practice to add it in package.json for maintenance, so we need this way to install it properly