# jquery not working in deployment but working in local nuxtjs?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

am using jquery to display a popup in my nuxt js app and working in localhost and development environment
nuxt.config.js

```js
script: [
  {
    src: "~plugins/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
    type: "text/javascript"
  },
],
plugins: [  
  "'~plugins/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
],
```

Comment: Please give more details as of what is happening on production if you want us to help you. [ask] Also, why is the script doing the same job as the plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to include jQuery in a Vue/Nuxt project (it's somehow counter-productive) but I guess that you can include it with a CDN and it will work flawlessly in any environment.

```js
script: [
  {
    src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
    type: "text/javascript"
  }
]
```

---

Or in this way, a bit cleaner

```
yarn add jquery
```

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ["jquery"],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery"
      })
    ],
  }
};
```

Example of setup taken from here: https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-use-jquery-in-nuxtjs

You can also try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57508835/8816585